# QStyledItemDelegate / QAbstractItemDelegate for QListView

Tags: c++, qt, qlistview, qstyleditemdelegate

My aim is to create something like contact app, where I can list contacts and choose it to see information about person. I figure out that one of the possible solution is to use QListView + QStyledItemDelegate / QAbstractItemDelegate. The information about it is very difficult so I don't understand it clearly;

(Contact should look something like https://www.sketchappsources.com/free-source/4395-ios-contacts-screen-app-sketch-freebie-resource.html)

So how should I use QAbstractItemDelegate ( I heard that I must reimplement paintEvent )?

Comment: Have you seen the [stars example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-stardelegate-example.html)? It's not clear to me what specifically is your problem but if it's about the fancy icons in the rows (in your sample link), the stars example seems to be quite close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to start with a data model.

1. Use `QStandardItemModel` class for beginning and populate it with `QStandardItem` class instances. It would allow you to set icon, text, font, background, size and other properties for items. Refer to https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#details
2. Set your model to `QListView` using `setModel`
3. To handle items clicked connect to `QListView`'s `clicked` signal.

To render items in more complex way you should

1. Override `QStyledItemDelegate` class and it's `paint` and `sizeHint` methods. In the `paint` method you should implement rendering and your `sizeHint` method should return a valid size for items. Refer to https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemdelegate.html#details
2. To get item data to render use `data` method of `QModelIndex` reference that is passed to `paint` method. Use different roles to get appropriate data. Refer to https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum
3. Use your delegate class by setting it to `QListView` by `setItemDelegate`.

Model should be set to QListView and item clicks are handled in same way.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll try this soon. I'll ask if its some questions